# Ask turtles to stop moving

Tags: netlogo

I would like to ask turtles in the car? to stop moving once they change colour. This is the code I tried but the output does not change.

```
let moving (turtles) with [ car? ] 
 if any? moving
      [  ask moving [stop] ]
```

I also tried this

```
if any? turtles with [ car?] 
    [ stop ]
```

which stops the entire simulation once there's a turtle with car?. Car? is a turtle-own.
I would like (turtles) with [ car? ] to not move at all.
Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Turtles only move when you tell them to, it's not like you start moving them and they continue to do so until you tell them not to. So presumably you have some code somewhere that actually moves turtles that looks something like:

```
ask turtles with [car?] [move]
```

Instead, only move the ones you want, something like:

```
ask turtles with [car? and color = yellow] [move]
```

Alternatively, when you change their colour, you can also `set car? false` if the change in colour means that the person is walking or similar